# How to iterate through an array within the object in angular

Tags: angularjs

This is how the array is in the data:

```
$scope.persons = [{
 cc:["abqwQe12c", "iu63enWzy", "dj101OQaQ"]
},
 {
cc:["erie1wka", "irt2naszsd", "riger1OQ"]
}]
```

In html it displays as an array when called like this `{{person.cc}}`. But below doesn't give anything.

```
 <div ng-repeat = "person in persons"> 
   <div ng-repeat = "ccs in person"> 
    {{ccs.cc}} 
   </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the inner repeat to loop over the `person.cc` property array

```
 <div ng-repeat = "person in persons"> 
    <div ng-repeat = "ccs in person.cc"> 
       {{ccs}} 
     </div> 
 </div>
```